# Mismatch error in join operation (adodb)

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado, adodb, recordset

I get mismatch error in this code:

```
    rst.Open "SELECT [LINE], [TASK], [Frequency] FROM qqq LEFT JOIN dane ON _
(qqq.[IdTask] =  dane.[IdTask]) ;", cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTableDirect
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error. When I write [IdTask].qqq = [IdTask].dane instead of qqq.[IdTask] =  dane.[IdTask] I get syntax error in join operation.

Comment: If the error states it's a type mismatch, it usually is a type mismatch. However, you're not providing any information on the types of the different columns. Obviously, if you then also screw up the syntax, the error changes to syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely columns `qqq.[IdTask]` and `dane.[IdTask]` have different data type. Check this first.

Answer (score 0):

It's started working:

```
 rst.Open "SELECT [LINE], [TASK], [Frequency] FROM qqq LEFT JOIN dane ON_
 qqq.[IdTask] =  dane.[IdTask];",cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTableDirect
```